# How to create a .ipa file on windows without Xcode and without an Apple Developer Account

Tags: react-native, ipa, expo

I want to know how I can convert an app I wrote to a .ipa file. My app is written in react native, but I can't afford the Apple Developer Account to convert my app to a .ipa file using Expo. If possible, I want a solution that can convert an app written in any language or the popular ones.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot. You will need a xcode and mac for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With expo you can create ipa using this command:

```
exp build:ios
```

Follow this latest documentation of expo.. you just need to change your app.json file as they mention.

[Expo latest documentation for generating apk & ipa](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html)

```
Step 1: install exp:  npm install -g exp
Step 2: configure app.json file
Step 3: exp build:android or exp build:ios
```

> Note: for .ipa you should know your apple ID and password: once you
>   start building expo ask you for your apple ID n password
>
> ? How would you like to upload your credentials?  Expo handles all
>   credentials, you can still provide overrides
>
> We need your Apple ID/password to manage certificates and provisioning
>   profiles from your Apple Developer account.
>
> Note: Expo does not keep your Apple ID or your Apple password.
>
> ? What's your Apple ID?